# How to implement @Async in spring boot correctly in term of thread safety?

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

In spring boot when the web send a http request to a rest controller, the rest controller then may forward the request through the layer/s of the application (service, repository).
This process is guaranteed to be thread safe by spring.

As I'm quite new to multithreading, I came with the following question.

I have a specific request where the service layer is required to execute some calculation per a request. in order to not holding the user, I created a task service with method annoated with @Async.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
            
    @Autowired
    private MyTask myTask;
            
    @Async("taskExecutor")  
    public void launchCalc(Integer myId) {      
        ...             
        myTask.execute(myId);           
    }       
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public synchronized void execute(Integer myId) {                                                  
    ...
    someCalc(myId);                            
    ...
}
```

I'm able to see in the log entries like: TaskExecutor-6 TaskExecutor-8 etc which means spring allocating threads from the pool each time.

What I'm getting is errors such as the following:

```
    [ TaskExecutor-2][36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper SQL Error: 1213, SQLState: 40001
 [TaskExecutor-2][36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
```

So, I realized that multiple thread compete on resources so what I did is marking the main method
with syncronized.
All problems disappeared but now user will have to wait (not really wait becuase I forward to different page but he won't be able to see the results of the calc) not only to finished his data calculation but also others which cause a usabilty problem.

The benfit of using @Async is minimal in this case, is there a way to do it better?

Comment: Using `syncronized` with `@Async` basically defeats the purpose of `@Async` as you made it syncronized again, yet even worse you can only handle 1 request at a time and have crippled it. Nor will this work if you deploy multiple instances of your application. The problem is different and shouldn't be "solved" with syncronized. You are trying to do something with the same resource/entity/record on the database and you decided you need a lock for this. Do you really need it.

Comment: The syncronized is not the solution, I added it to the question just to demonstrate the problem, do I need to work on make the code thread safe? If yes, then what the error indicates? I need a starting point...

Comment: As stated apparently you decided that you need to lock something in the database (maybe unknowingly but still). There is nothing in here that isn't thread-safe, the problem is the database lock (that is what your exception is telling).

Comment: The lock is not done by me, it's happened without my knowing, something in the transaction cause this. As I have many saves/updates it looks like I need to isolate the problem by executing part and see where is the problem.

Comment: Well you either have this in your query or, when using JPA, instructed your JPA provider to acquire a lock. If you want more information we need to see some code and the actuall **full stacktrace** and not a snippet.

Comment: Have a look in my answer, maybe you can comment. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours on running again and again, I was able to isolate some
methods and found the following.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public synchronized void execute(Integer myId) {                                                  
    ...
    someCalc(myId);                            
    ...
}
```

The method execute is the only method which has the annotation @Transactional.
someCalc(myId) is calling other methods within the same class which means by definition the same transaction applied or being used by those methods.

Now, one of the first method is doing repository.findById and save the entity to a member of the class. This was the main problem I think.

When debugging I saw that the entityId does not matches the entityId
in the children. So it looks like two threads come to a method and use different states.

In order to solve these errors what I did is calling repository.findById on the called methods (in each one of them) and load lazily the children when applicable.
The main method transfer the entityId only.

While I'm posting this as a solution I must say that I am not confident as two
threads can come to the same method one will load the entity by id and the other might use this entity.

The test is done by a loop of only 20.

Comment: **Never** store state in a member variable. Ditch that approach as that is **not thread safe**. If you need it store it in a variable inside the method that way it is only visible to 1 thread.

Comment: What about transforming ArrayList from 1 method to another? or better to retrieve the list in the local method?

Comment: What do you think method arguments and return values are for? Don't pass state throuygh storing them as member variables, that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: Well, I can avoid sending the ArrayList BUT I must send the entityId in order to retrive all relevant data

Comment: The `entityId` isn't the problem, it is storing the state that is the problem.

Comment: Storing the state is already fixed, no class member is used. I'll also retieve the ArrayList using the entity id and will work on running 5000 as the next step (I don't have populate function for 5000 entities yet).